# Variable as an object and/or array

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

I ask my question, I want detect in php variable must be an object or an array...

This my code :
Dispatcher.php

```
<?php
class Dispatcher {
   var $request;

   public function __construct(){
      $this->request = new Request();
      var_dump($this->request->query);
   }
}

?>
```

Request.php

```
<?php
class Request {
   public $query = false;
   public function __construct(){
      if(!empty($_GET)){
         $this->query = array();
         foreach($_GET as $k => $v) {
            $this->query[$k] = $v;
         }
         //I need help here for mix array and stdClass();
      }
   }
}
?>
```

I also want to use `$this->request->query['page']` (array) and as object : `$this->request->query->page` with stdClass();
But I don't know how to do this...

Thanks for helping... :)

(Sorry for my bad english, I'm french ;)...)

Comment: Just a thought: PHP has [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php).  That's the only way you're going to get arrayish and objectish access through the same variable.  Truthfully, though, it's probably not worth the trouble.  (An object doesn't work with `array_map` etc.)  Just pick one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php)

```
$this->query = new ArrayObject($_GET, ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);

// use it in dispatcher
echo $this->request->query['page'];
echo $this->request->query->page;

// your also able to iterate
foreach ($this->request->query as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.'=>'.$value.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for ArrayObject!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
if(is_array($this->request->query))
{
   echo $this->request->query['page'];
}
elseif(is_object($this->request->query))
{
   echo $this->request->query->page;
}
else
{
   echo "not array or object";
}
```

Comment: Ever heard of DRY? This hurts my eyes.

Comment: @MightyPork Your eyes must hurt of the missing semicolons, not because DRY doesn't apply here.

Comment: Thanks to you both! Now I know what Dry is and I corrected my lines with semicolons... (this was intended to present is_array and is_object not as optimal code)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Oh it does apply here. If you cast the query to object as shown in my answer, you don't have to duplicate so much code.

Comment: @MightyPork You can't cast if you use PHP 5.4 >. And that's on some hosts the case (seriously, that's sick).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert array to object using a cast (as of PHP 5.4, I think).

For objects (stdclass), it won't do any harm.

```
$arr = array('foo'=>'bar');

$obj = (object) $arr;

echo $obj->foo;
```